# C++0x programming with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Has anyone done some programming with Qt using C++0x? How is it working out? Is it possible to use all the nice features of C++0x? What compiler and version are you using?

Im currently using gcc 4.6 and trying out all the c++0x features but i have not yet done anything with Qt.

Comment: This question is incredibly vague and seems to be asking for anecdotes and opinions.

Comment: @erjiang: It is a good question. I guess what is being asked is whether newer versions of Qt are going to take advantage of C++0x. I may be wrong though. @Per: Clarify your question please

Comment: I have not so much experience in QT more than knowing that it has some custom QT specific things like its own collections and such. What i am thinking about is more about if it is possible to take advantage of all the nice features of C++0x when working with QT like rangen based for, lambdas, auto etc. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Qt pretty much replaces all standard library features. As for core features, it definitely won't happen soon as Qt supports a wide range of compilers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like some of the C++0x standard will be implemented in Qt 4.8
http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/05/26/cpp0x-in-qt/

Comment: If you make it to the bottom of that article, it explicitely states you can compile Qt 4.7 with a C++0x compiler, or compile your own code with 0x support even though Qt itself was not.  So you might not get all the benefits just yet, but you'll get some.

Answer (score 1):

Range-based for should be possible as Qt's containers have the standard container interface, more or less.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Qt doesn't use any C++0x features itself (as far as I know), it is certainly possible to write C++0x code that uses Qt.  Problems could arise if any of the new syntax confuses the `moc` parser, but that should only matter in classes containing the `Q_OBJECT` macro.