# Qt support for C++0x enum class

Tags: c++, qt, enums, c++11, qobject

Using [Q_ENUMS](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#Q_ENUMS) I can now "register" with Qt an `enum` declared inside a class that inherists from `QObject`. This gives me a few cool reflection features for the `enum`.

I'm also really enjoying the type-safe `enum class` introduced in C++0x. I'm wondering if you know of any announcement made by Qt developers of plans for support for the `enum class`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4178297/627517) vaguely asks about Qt support of C++0x features in general. I'm asking specifically about `enum class`. I realize that since Qt is cross-platform and supports many compilers, support for C++0x will be SLOW to roll out, but `enum class` is a very nice simple improvement of the core language!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that Qt 4.8 will have support for many major C++0x features (including `enum class`) according to [this blog post](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/05/26/cpp0x-in-qt/).