# QMetaEnum and strong typed enum

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, enums, strong-typing

With plain enums I was able to access Q_ENUMS properties and specific, the character represenation of enums, with following code:

```
// in .h
class EnumClass : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  enum  MyEnumType { TypeA, TypeB };
  Q_ENUMS(MyEnumType)
private:
  MyEnumType m_type;
};

// in .cpp
m_type = TypeA;
...
const QMetaObject &mo = EnumClass::staticMetaObject;
int index = mo.indexOfEnumerator("MyEnumType");
QMetaEnum metaEnum = mo.enumerator(index);
QString enumString = metaEnum.valueToKey(m_type); // contains "TypeA"
```

If I want to use the c++11 feature for *strong typed enums* like

```
enum class MyEnumType { TypeA, TypeB };
```

accessing the meta information does not work anymore. I guess, that Qt does not recognize it as an enum anymore.

Is there any solution to access the character represenation of an enum while using strong typed enums?

Comment: Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: we are using still qt4.8, but are going to switch to qt5 whenever we find the time for that.

Comment: I'm not _entirely_ sure, but this may be because of your Qt version. Also, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513736/qt-support-for-c0x-enum-class

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: you are right, according to your link 4.8 does only support some features of C++0x, strong typed enums is not among those. I tried qt 5.2.1 and it did work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Q_ENUMS` is obsolete, and `Q_ENUM` should be used instead, but the following code works for me with either of them (Qt 5.5, your issue might be caused by an old Qt version; also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513736/qt-support-for-c0x-enum-class) is relevant):

.h:

```
#include <QObject>
class EnumClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum class MyEnumType { TypeA, TypeB };
    EnumClass();
    Q_ENUM(MyEnumType)
private:
    MyEnumType m_type;
};
```

.cpp:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMetaEnum>
#include <QMetaObject>
EnumClass::EnumClass()
{
    m_type = MyEnumType::TypeA;
    const QMetaObject &mo = EnumClass::staticMetaObject;
    int index = mo.indexOfEnumerator("MyEnumType");
    QMetaEnum metaEnum = mo.enumerator(index);
    // note the explicit cast:
    QString enumString = metaEnum.valueToKey(static_cast<int>(m_type));
    qDebug() << enumString;
}
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    EnumClass asd;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> "TypeA"

Comment: According to your link 4.8 does only support some features of C++0x, strong typed enums is not among those. I tried qt 5.2.1 with Q_ENUMS, since Q_ENUM was introduced with qt 5.5, and it does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Q_ENUM macro and template with QMetaEnum:

in.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QMetaEnum>

template<typename T>
QString enumToString(T value)
{
    int castValue = static_cast<int>(value);
    return QMetaEnum::fromType<T>().valueToKey(castValue);
}

class Enum : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum class Color {
        NO_COLOR = 0,
        RED,
        GREEN,
        BLUE,
    };

    Q_ENUM(Color)

    Enum();
    Enum(Color color);
    QString toString();

private:
    Color m_value {Color::NO_COLOR};
};
```

in.cpp:

```
#include "in.h"

Enum::Enum()
{
}

Enum::Enum(Color color = Color::NO_COLOR) : m_value(color)
{
}


QString Enum::toString()
{
    return enumToString(m_value);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "in.h"

#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    Enum none;
    Enum red(Enum::Color::RED);
    Enum green(Enum::Color::GREEN);
    Enum blue(Enum::Color::BLUE);

    qDebug() << none.toString();
    qDebug() << red.toString() << green.toString() << blue.toString();

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> "NO_COLOR"
> "RED" "GREEN" "BLUE"

Answer (score 0):

When using `enum class` , cast the type to `int` in `valueToKey()`:

For a `QObject` class , we ca directly use `QMetaEnum`  , this direct approach should and actually works, both getting key and value ; tested Qt_5_10

declaration:

```
class EnumClass : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  enum class MyEnumType { TypeA, TypeB };
  Q_ENUM(MyEnumType)
...
};
```

Usage:

```
   QMetaEnum metaEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<EnumClass::MyEnumType>();
   qDebug() << metaEnum.valueToKey(static_cast<int>(EnumClass::MyEnumType::TypeA));
   qDebug() << metaEnum.keyToValue("TypeB");
```

...

result :

"TypeA"

1